# How do i get the primary id (pid) for a document in CM8.4 using the Item ID and Component ID?

Tags: content-management-system

Im using IBM Content Manager 8.4.1 and I need to write some code to retreive documents.  The information I have is the Item ID and Component ID which im retreiving from the document views under the ICMADMIN (Default) Schema.

The below block gives a sample using DKPidICM object to generate the primary id (pid) used to get a workpackage but I want to get a document instead and need to know what is different.

```
DKPidICM pidicm = new DKPidICM();
pidicm.setComponentId(compId);
pidicm.setItemId(itemId);
pidicm.setDatastoreName(datastoreName);
pidicm.setComponentTypeId("204");
pidicm.setVersionNumber("1");
pidicm.setObjectType("WORKPACKAGE");
pidicm.setDatastoreType("ICM");
pidicm.getPrimaryId();
```

To retreive a document what do i need to set for

- Component Type ID
- Object Type

Or is there a better way all together

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the component type id is based directly on the item type you are looking for so the Name from the system adminstration client under the item.

The most straight foward way I found to determine the componentTypeId was to:

1).query for that item type `queryService.setQueryString(**"/itemTypeName"**, CMBBaseConstant.CMB_QS_TYPE_XPATH);`

2).Create the corresponding DKPidICM `DKPidICM pidicm = new DKPidICM(pidString)`

3).Get the componentID from that `pidicm.getComponentTypeId()`

**More complete Sample below**

```
    CMBQueryService queryService = cmbConnection.getQueryService();
    queryService.setAsynchSearch(false); // synchronous search
    queryService.setMaxResults(1);

    queryService.setQueryString("/itemTypeName", CMBBaseConstant.CMB_QS_TYPE_XPATH);
    queryService.runQuery();

    CMBResultData results = (CMBResultData) queryService.getResults();

    CMBSearchResults searchResults = new CMBSearchResults();
    searchResults.setConnection(cmbConnection);
    searchResults.newResults(results);

    if (searchResults.getCount() > 0) {
        String pidString = searchResults.getItem(0).getPidString();
        DKPidICM pidicm = new DKPidICM(pidString);

        return pidicm.getComponentTypeId();
```